# XPath Query (with some simple regex restrictions)

Tags: xml, regex, xpath

Consider I got the following piece of XML?

```
<result>
    <_id>-3:1</_id>
    <_ver>0</_ver>
    <_class>Address</_class>
    <type>Residence</type>
    <street>Piazza di Spagna</street>
    <city>-4:0</city>
</result>
```

What would be the xpath to query each of the following:

1. For all tags that are not beginning with “_”. 
   So I would expect something like: type, street, city
2. The text body for all tags that are not beginning with “_”. 
   So I would expect something like: Residence, Piazza di Spagna, -4:0

Comment: Thanks guys... although I would prefer the XPath 1.0 solution to ensure greater compatibility. Although, is there any particular reason why the XPath 2.0 solution would be superior?

Comment: There isn't a big difference between the XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 solution. The latter produces for 2. a *sequence* of strings (should correspond to a list of items in the host language), while the XPath 1.0 solution produces a node-set (represented as list of nodes in the host language) of text-nodes. I think the solution of @Martin-Honnen for 1. is wrong -- it produces the names of the elements, that don't start with '_'. If you really want the element-names to be produced, there isn't an single XPath 1.0 expression that can produce this. I think you want the elements -- not just their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using XPath 1.0** (and, of course, this is also XPath 2.0 solution):

1. `/*/*[not(starts-with(name(), '_'))]`
2. `/*/*[not(starts-with(name(), '_'))]/text()`

Answer (score 2):

With XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 you can use

1. `/result/*/local-name(.)[not(starts-with(., '_'))]`
2. `/result/*[not(starts-with(local-name(), '_'))]/string(.)`